# Dimension and Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

What did I do wrong, could you please help me identify? So I have been asked to show that

> every set of $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space are linearly dependent, using the fact that  a set of linearly independent vectors in a finite-dimensional vector space, can be extended to a basis if not already a basis.

*My solution:*

Any list of independent vectors may be extended to a basis, but no two bases may have a different number of elements, and the number of elements of a basis is equal to the dimension of the vector space. Hence, from the given fact the set of $n+1$ independent vectors may be extended to be a basis if not already, but then it would lead to a contradiction since a basis of an $n$-dimensional vector space can't have more than $n$ elements. Thus the assumption in the first place that we can have $n+1$ linearly  independent vectors is incorrect.

Comment: "Hence, from the given fact the set of n+1 independent vectors"  No such fact is present.

Comment: It seems to me that the reasoning is correct. Except that the phrase should be clarified as follows: if our system of $n+1$ vectors is linearly independent, then it can be extended to a basis or is already a basis.